# Does SDF format not working with ROS?

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I m at the beginning of simulation a robot. So Before start I made some research for start point. The biggest contradiction that I face up is: Should I start my design with SDF of URFD format. ( I want to use my design in Gazebo, rviz and ROS )

As I read from this [article](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf) : SDF is a complete description for everything from the world level down to the robot level. And it has also some more advantages like  easy adding and modify elements.

As I read from this [article](https://autonomousbot.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/urdf-vs-sdf/) : it is described that difference
between SDF & URFD is ;  URDF works with the rest of the Robot Operating System (ROS) and SDF really only works with Gazebo.

So again the question on that point :
-Does ROS not support the SDF format ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276227/does-sdf-format-not-working-with-ros-?/) by [Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/32512/robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kaveh_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/101393/kaveh_ros/) on 2022-07-25**:
you can use  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8g5nMxhi_Pw) to convert your sdf files to urdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not support the SDF format. Gazebo provides the `gzsdf` tool to translate from URDF to SDF. [This article describes](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf) how to add Gazebo tags to an URDF file; `gzsdf` will pass these tags along in the final SDF.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1